# Quit Less with Pexpect

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, pexpect

I have 3 files, `a.py`, `b.sh`, and `text.txt`. Their contents follow:

a.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, pexpect

class zz:
    def __init__(self):
        child = pexpect.spawn ('/home/usr/Desktop/b.sh')

        ###  VVV     LINE IN QUESTION BELOW    VVV
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)

        child.sendline('q')
        child.interact()

z = zz()
```

b.sh:

```
less /home/usr/Desktop/text.txt
echo 'all done'
sleep 3
```

text.txt:

```
thisistext
```

Files `text.txt` and `b.sh` are read-only and must not be changed. How does one quit `less` using [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) from within `a.py`?

Comment: you have `bc.sh` in your `spawn` line. Is that as intended? Good luck.

Comment: No- that was an error in copying it over to stackoverflow. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hard to determine your goal here. It seems like you could just use `cat .../text.txt`. If you want a user to be able to user the interactive features of `less`, then how/why should `pexpect` be involved? There is an option to `less` that will display and close the file, (I think), or if not other cmd-line opts to less or the LESS envvar may help you. Good luck.

Comment: `b.sh` is readonly- it's subject to updates, so I can't change the less command in it due to an external, updated `b.sh` script overwriting my patch all the time. If I could, I would just delete `less` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to do anything with the data, just read the first screen of data from less and then issue the 'q'.

(EDIT: This needed a tweak to give 'read' a size so that it didn't wait for the default size or eof)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, pexpect

class zz:
    def __init__(self):
        child = pexpect.spawn ('/home/usr/Desktop/b.sh')
        # grab the first screen from 'less'
        child.read(1)
        child.send('q')

z = zz()
```

Here is the code I used for test:

```
~/tmp/reader$ cat a.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

try:
    open('status.txt', 'w')
    child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/sh "./b.sh"', timeout=10)
    child.send('q')
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
except Exception,e:
    print 'exception'
print open('status.txt').read()


~/tmp/reader$ cat text.txt
iamtext

~/tmp/reader$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/sh
less text.txt
echo 'all done'
sleep 3
date > status.txt
```

Comment: This isn't working. If I tell b.sh to touch `run.txt` on it's last line, no file is created if `child.read()` is used.

Comment: @mh00h - I was surprised! I tested pexpect with less directly and just assumed it would work through a shell command. Anyway, I think it will work if you include a size in the read call. I've posted the test I used.